# how to convert XIB iPhone app into story board iPhone app

Tags: ios

i have an calendar XIB iPhone app and which shows the simple calendar, now i want to use that calendar as a story board iPhone app, simple i want to convert that calendar app into story board iPhoe app, from apple documents , we can add story board in the XIB app but not the convert the whole app

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so?I dont think there is nothing more or less an storyboard can do over xib other than  the seague and its action?

Comment: yes off course, but i know a little bit more about storyboard than XIB and i want to continue it in story boradn, and i m nubee in Xcode,plz tell me how i can convert it if any solution is there

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a storyboard add all the components to the storyboard [use option+drg to copy] then do the connections and do then necessary changes in code for actions in presentation and proceed

Comment: i know this hierarchy but i go to apply this, there happens two errors, one comes into main,i don't know how to avoid this,plz help